# Why can I not add a TextView to my LinearLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am having a bunch of trouble adding a TextView to my LinearLayout. Here is what I have:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some button text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setText("Hello, world!");

        mainLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors in LogCat, it just doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the spacing between your views is correct

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some button text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also try `mainLayout.addView(newView, 0);` to add it before the button for verification

Comment: Ok, so switching from `mainLayout.addView(newView);` to `mainLayout.addView(newView, 0);` worked! It showed my text before the button. What I don't understand is why it wouldn't append it after the button in my original code.

Comment: Is that a complete code?, because i have tried it and its working super fine in both cases

Comment: No ... not complete. I wanted to keep my post as short as possible.

Comment: I understand . . . . Just upload it :) so people can help.

Comment: I would love to, but it is on a laptop that cannot be connected to the internet. Since it worked for you, I'll assume I have something obscuring the text. I'll keep looking at it to see if I can figure it out. Thanks again. Also, what did you mean by "Make sure the spacing between your views is correct"?

Answer (score 2):

There is no space for your `TextView` because `Button` is taking them all.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="some button text" />
```

Change it to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Brian is right. There is also an typo in the first line. I guess it should be android.com

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

and not android/com.